# How do you say “so much so” in French?

Tags: traduction

I want to say the following sentence in French:

> Person1: I want you to make it to the farm so much so that I’ll even
>   apologise to Jake.

Comment: Hi! Did you try something like Wiktionary or some other dictionary and did you try phrasing the rest of the sentence with what you found?

Comment: Please, show us how you think it could be translated, and we'll help you and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You do find several renderings in [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/so%20much%20so).

Only the last choice can be considered as a solution for the given sentence.

- **à telle enseigne que** - **au point que** - **si bien que** - **tellement**

However here it is more precisely "so much so that" that you need to consider, and on the web page indicated above you get the following translations for this locution.

- *so much so that*,  expr  (to such a degree that) : **tant et si bien que** (loc. conj.)
      **à tel point que** (loc. conj.)

You can add "**à ce point que**", "**à un tel point que**" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+un+tel+point+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20un%20tel%20point%20que%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20un%20tel%20point%20que%3B%2Cc0)) and "**tellement que**".

There would be no problem if you could just swap those locutions wherever they are found in sentences, but you can't always do that; in the present case you can't.

You must use the second one or the variant  "**à un tel point que**".

- Je veux **à (un) tel point que** vous réussissiez/tu réussisses à la ferme que je suis même prêt/prête à faire des excuses à Jake.

It wouldn't be wrong to use "tellement que" instead; the somewhat lesser intensity imparted by this latter choice can for instance be  compensated by special stress and intonation in pronouncing it.

- Je veux **tellement que** vous réussissiez/tu réussisses à la ferme que je suis même prêt/prête à faire des excuses à Jake.

Answer (score 0):

"I want you to make it to the farm so much so that I’ll even apologise to Jake." can be translated by

Je veux tant et si bien que vous réussissiez à la ferme que j'envisage même de présenter mes excuses à Jake.